# Dynamics AX How I can open a table in a brand new window and not inside developer window

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, morph-x

A dummy quastion regarding AX 2012, Do you know how to open a table window from AOT  in a brand new window?? At the moment my cliet opens the tables from the AOT inside the developer window and not as indipendent windows as in the past.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by customizing the `SysTableBrowser` design node attibute `WindowType` from `Popup` to `Standard`.